# Umbraco Multiple Media Picker doesn't delete items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I have an Umbraco v7 site that has a document type with a multiple media picker field.

After I store some initial data in there by selecting a file in the media section, this data won't be removed from the front end. I clear the selection and then save and publish. I can then refresh the backoffice page and it sure looks deleted, but in the front end that selection is still there.

In the fron end file I access the value like this:

```
Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("relatedDownloads")
```

For some reason this returns a CSV of media ID's even when those items have been removed from the selection of the content item.

In the database, I can see that the records have been deleted (checking in the `[cmsPropertyData]` table)

Any other assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a publishing issue, try to "Republish entire site".

[image]